# Can the result set of inner query can be displayed with final result set

Tags: sql, postgresql, inner-query

I have a table that contains some data say

```
====================
Record  | Record_Count
1       |   12
3       |   87
5       |   43
6       |   54
1       |   43
3       |   32
5       |   65
6       |   43
```

I have a query that returns Record Count sum grouped by Record

```
select record,sum(record_count)
FROM table_name
WHERE <conditions>
GROUP BY tcpa_code
ORDER BY sum(record_count)
```

The result is something like this

```
====================
Record  | Record_Count
1       |   55
3       |   119
5       |   108
6       |   97
```

Now I also want a grand total of record_count (Sum of all record Count).

The thing is I want the above result set along with the grand total also.

I had tried this

```
select sum(subquery.record_count)
from (
select record,sum(record_count)
FROM table_name
WHERE <conditions>
GROUP BY tcpa_code
ORDER BY sum(record_count) ) as subquery
```

But by using this I am losing the individual record_count sum.

So my question is can I achieve result set that contains record_count sum for each record and grand total of record_count in a single query?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `union` to achieve what you need:

```
(select cast(record as varchar(16)) record,sum(record_count) from schema.table
group by 1)
union
(select 'Grand_Total' as record,sum(record_count) from schema.table
group by 1);
```

Check here - **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e67bc/4)**

---

If your DB supports `group by ... with rollup`, you may also use:

```
select ifnull(record,'Grand Total')record,sum(record_count) total_count
from schema.table
group by record asc with rollup
```

Check here - **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e67bc/10)**

Answer (score 0):

To save some typing, a *common table expression* (cte) can be used:

```
with cte as
(
    select record, sum(record_count) rsum
    FROM table_name
    WHERE <conditions>
    GROUP BY record
)
select record, rsum from cte
union all
select 'Grand_Total', sum(rsum) from cte
```

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize [windows functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-window.html) of PostgrSQL.

As for this query,

```
SELECT record, record_count, sum(record_count) OVER()
    FROM (
         SELECT record, sum(record_count) record_count
           FROM table_name
           WHERE <conditions>
           GROUP BY tcpa_code
           ORDER BY sum(record_count) 
          ) as subquery
```